# Traditionally, why are 'pasta bowls' wide and shallow?

Tags: pasta, history

I was curious as to why they're marketed as pasta bowls in the UK, and it's because they're frequently used for pasta (obviously). Buy why are bowls used for pasta traditionally wide and relatively shallow? As opposed to other types of bowl?

The reasons I can think of are potentially to do with serving size (i.e. can fit more in the bowl) or thermodynamics (larger surface area to allow faster cooling). But I don't know why either of these would specifically apply to pasta dishes.

For context, this is what is generally considered a pasta bowl here in the UK as far as I'm aware:
[image]
As compared to a cereal/all-purpose bowl:
[image]
Or a soup bowl/lipped bowl:
[image]
I understand that a 'pasta bowl' is not exclusively for pasta dishes and I know that other types of bowl are also used when it comes to serving pasta. But I'm interested in why, in the UK at least, a 'pasta bowl' is sold as such.

Comment: What would you call a "normal" bowl? Soup plate, cereal bowl… one has a rim, the other doesn't… Also a quick Google for 'pasta bowl' shows up both types [& many other variations] though scrolling down shows me more rimless than rimmed.

Comment: @Tetsujin here pasta bowls are generally rimless and wide, while a 'normal' bowl can be like a cereal bowl or a rimmed bowl. I did check Google for an answer before I asked :)

Comment: We don't know where 'here' is, & you still haven't defined what you consider to be a 'normal' bowl. What is 'normal' depends on the style of the dinner service, & the intended purpose.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've added some context, I'm in the UK.

Comment: I'm a little confused. In your question you say that pasta bowls traditionally have a wide rim. But the picture you posted of a pasta bowl doesn't have a rim. Then in comments you say that pasta bowls are generally rimless and wide. Can you please edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Could this just be marketing?  A lot of pasta is eaten from all of those bowls, and, in fact, it might be just as common to serve it on a plate, depending on the recipe of course.

Comment: @Cindy Sorry, when I wrote the question my Google results used 'wide rim' as rimless and wide. To be honest I never thought about rims/lips or bowl terminology before...

Comment: @moscafj That's a possibility, would be interesting to know why though

Comment: @Lyall To sell bowls!

Comment: The question is still contradictory, can you please edit it so that it's not?

The reason I ask is that here in the US the "soup bowl" you have on the bottom is often sold as a "pasta bowl".

Comment: @FuzzyChef I've made some updates to the question to try and help clarify - I hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah, that works.

Comment: I think I've also seen the soup plate shown in the question sold as a pasta bowl, while my pasta bowls are wide with vertical sides

Answer (score 7):

My hypothesis is that there is no functional reason for having a wide rim on a pasta bowl.  I contend that this is simply marketing, and the choice of the person presenting the meal. It is just a name for a bowl.  Pasta is served in all sorts of vessels; plates, deep bowls, shallow bowls.  Saucing, in part, determines the vessel.  For example, you can't serve tortellini in brodo on a plate.  Plates, bowls, and dishes are often designed and chosen for the way they compliment a final dish's visual appeal.  The Chinese (and other noodle eating cultures) don't necessarily eat noodles from wide-rimmed bowls, and I would confidently guess that you wouldn't have to look that far back to find a time that there was really was no such thing presented as a wide-rimmed, pasta bowl.  So, I would say that this is not a tradition at all.  This is a product of restaurants, ceramic makers, and the media (magazines and food TV).

Comment: It's just like all the different wine glasses, with a different glass for each varietal.  Lots of folks don't realize that "tradition" was created by Reidel.

Comment: Id wager that the wider rim is for laying hunks / slices of bread on without them falling vertically into the dish ;-) At least that's how we used them at some of restaurants I've worked at. So yes, presentation.